# First attempt to learn about Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a button on Main's android xml file which once clicked will display another view/activity. 
My problem is the error message displays that the application must end unexpectedly.

Here is the button

```
<Button android:id="@+id/showmeurcode"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="OnShowMeUrCode"
>
```

The method OnShowMeUrCode is defined in the MainActivity class as

```
private void OnShowMeUrCode(View btn)
{
    Intent urCode=new Intent(this,CodePage.class);
    startActivity(urCode);
}
```

`CodePage` is generated from a class of the same name

```
public class CodePage extends Activity
{
   ....
}
```

That is all I have done in the hope that I could accomplish the simple task with Intent to display another view but I run in an unexpected error and my program fails short.

Comment: You should always your LogCat errors if your app crashes.

Comment: Sorry I left out a word: "always *post* your". Simply cut & paste the LogCat errors into your question so we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your OnShowMeUrCode() function to be public, not private.  Since it's part of the Activity class, your Button won't have access to it if it's private.

Plus it's in the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code without the error log output, I guess you didn't pass a correct Context to the method.

This is your code:

```
private void OnShowMeUrCode(View btn)
{
    Intent urCode=new Intent(this,CodePage.class);
    startActivity(urCode);
}
```

Try replace the relevant line with:

`Intent urCode=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CodePage.class);`

Say, I have two Activities, A and B. If I'm calling B from A, I should write something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Besides, you need to register your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml each time you create a new activity. In your case, please check if there are 2 activities in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: +1 for the AndroidManifest.xml suggestion. -1 for the context suggestion - the context is not the problem as `MainActivity.this` is the same as just `this` in this case. So overall, +/- 0 on your answer.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg thx for the suggestion :) I have to guess the problem because the asker provided no logcat to reveal where might the problem be.